# Is there a way to get my "Author" field prepopulating in my Django form?

Tags: python, django

I am making a review site and I have a Movie, Game, Show, and Review model and within my Review model I have "author" which is a foreign key and in my review form I have the "author" field and I want it to be populated with the username of the user that is logged in and leaving the review, I have searched this site and googled for hours and can't seem to find any solution ill leave my code I have at the moment below. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
class Review(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reviewer')
    review_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    scores = (
        (1, 1),
        (2, 2),
        (3, 3),
        (4, 4),
        (5, 5),
        (6, 6),
        (7, 7),
        (8, 8),
        (9, 9),
        (10, 10)
    )
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    stars = models.IntegerField(choices=scores)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=4000)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='reviews')
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='reviews')
    show = models.ForeignKey(Show, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='reviews')
    media_type = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, default=None)
    media_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, default=None)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Review {self.comment} by {self.author}'
```

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ('author', 'stars', 'comment',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['author'].disabled = True
```

```
def review(request, media_type, media_id):
    if media_type == 'movie':
        media = Movie.objects.get(id=media_id)
    elif media_type == 'game':
        media = Game.objects.get(id=media_id)
    elif media_type == 'show':
        media = Show.objects.get(id=media_id)
    else:
        raise Http404

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReviewForm(request.POST, initial={'author': request.user})
        if form.is_valid():
            review = form.save(commit=False)
            review.author = get_initial(self)
            review.media_type = media_type
            review.media_id = media_id
            if review.media_type == 'movie':
                review.movie = media
            elif review.media_type == 'game':
                review.game = media
            elif review.media_type == 'show':
                review.show = media
            review.save()
    else:
        form = ReviewForm()

    context = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'review.html', context)
```

I have tried forcing it by using review.author = request.user, in my views.py and I have also tried it with request.user.username and finally I tried to do it using initials

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question and post your code in codeblocks instead of pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only provide initial data to your form when `request.method == 'POST'`. Instead you want to **pre**populate the form, right? Therefore you need to pass initial data on `'GET'`request.

```py
[...]
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ReviewForm(request.POST)  # no initial here
    if form.is_valid():
        review = form.save(commit=False)
        review.author = get_initial(self)
        review.media_type = media_type
        review.media_id = media_id
        if review.media_type == 'movie':
            review.movie = media
        elif review.media_type == 'game':
            review.game = media
        elif review.media_type == 'show':
            review.show = media
        review.save()
else:
    form = ReviewForm(initial={'author': request.user})  # when GET request you also want to provide initial data!
[...]
```

Comment: Oh my god no way, I feel like a tool thank you so much something so simple and I was looking at it for hours, thank you!!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Actually take notice of my edits. I think you should **not** pass initial data on `POST` request. Normal django behaviour fills the form on `POST` request with before entered data. You don't want to override that.